# Visual Basic 2010 - "function" not declared

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I started a few days ago to write a Macro. It basically only consists of an UI in wich you can choose some options and based on those it gives you a couple of pages of a word document. It will be started from the .exe in the bin/release folder of the project.

I want to add a footer and a header for each page, but I have not been able to do so.

Whenever I want to use a functionality similar to: "wdHeaderFooterPrimary" as in:

```
objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Selection.TypeText("")

With objWord.Selection
    .Paragraphs.Alignment = 2
    .Font.size = 9
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
End With

With objWord.Sections(1)
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Header text"
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Footer text"
End With
```

It gives me an error, underlining the "wdHeader....". Up to now I have always found a workaround whenever I needed a functionality beginning with "wd...". 
But now I seem to have hit a wall. 
(I got some code from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221968(v=office.11).aspx )

Can someone explain to me how to use it properly? Do I have to change settings?
I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express to write the VBA code.

Edit:
The exact error is: 
"wdheaderFooterPrimary" was not declared. 
(translation following for 2nd part:)  Perhaps the object could not be accessed based on its security level (?)

Comment: changing the "objWord.Sections(1)" to "objDoc.Sections(1)" did not help.

Comment: The code you linked to is VBA.  If you're using Visual Studio, you're programming in VB.NET - these are different programming languages. See [this example on MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316383) for a better starting point.

Comment: huh. good to know :D thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a wordtemplate.dot file where I included the header/footer as I wanted and loading it into the application when creating a new file.

Answer (score -1):

As a definite solution to the problem, I found this through my researches, tried to work precisely, I give the code;

.ActiveDocument.Sections.Item (1) .Footers.Item (1) .Range.text = "Write your own text"